# Перевод кода с языка Pascal в C

Tags: pascal, c

Помогите перевести данный код на С:

```
begin
  ch:=random(100);
  write(ch, ' ');
  if ch mod 2 = 0 then inc(cnt)
  else if ((ch mod 2 <> 0) and (ch > max)) then max:=ch;
end;
```

Comment: А в чем, собственно, проблема?

Comment: Точней, как записать на с:

    ch:=random(100); 

И вот эту:

    if ch mod 2 = 0 then inc(cnt)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ch=rand()%100+1;
printf("%c ",ch);
if(ch%2==0) cnt++;
else if(ch>max) max=ch;
```

Comment: И обратите внимание на отсутствие бесполезной проверки условия
(ch mod 2 <> 0)